# Why is my restore of the Core Data files not found by app?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios8.1, magicalrecord-2.2

**UPDATED:** I am trying to backup and restore my Core Data files (using journaling and MagicalRecord based on [issue #444](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues?q=444)).  When running under the iOS simulator, I know that the files are moved each time from the last execution of the app. [Here](http://pastebin.com/M5Us5xkx) is the complete code (I put it here because it's lengthly and now it's formatted and syntax is highlighted, making it easier to read).

I can find the new location when the app starts, retrieve my stored files and do my restore from the files in the Documents directory, placing them in the correct new location as determined by console output from NSLog statements (it doesn't show the -shm file being restored but it was to the same location).

> AppDelegate-sqliteFilePath: /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/B424CA1A-D41C-488D-A7E9-0F13CB2244B3/Library/Application Support/SalonBook
>
> SVC-sqliteFilePath: /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/B424CA1A-D41C-488D-A7E9-0F13CB2244B3/Library/Application Support/SalonBook
>
> documentsBasePath: /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/B424CA1A-D41C-488D-A7E9-0F13CB2244B3/Documents
>
> starting - storePath: /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/B424CA1A-D41C-488D-A7E9-0F13CB2244B3/Library/Application Support/SalonBook/saori.sqlite
>
> Finished! storePath: /Users/rolfmarsh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1EE69744-255A-45CD-88F1-63FEAD117B32/data/Containers/Data/Application/B424CA1A-D41C-488D-A7E9-0F13CB2244B3/Library/Application Support/SalonBook/saori.sqlite-wal

When I start the restore, I issue:

```
[MagicalRecord cleanUp];  //  disable Core Data
```

When I finish the restore, I issue the following:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"saori.sqlite"];  //  enable Core Data migration
defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];   //  set default NSManagedObjectContext for MagicalRecord
```

When I look at the records that *should be* in the Core Data store (using SQLite Browser), they **are** in the sqlite file (saori.sqlite) but they do not appear in the app!  It's like the MR stack wasn't set up correctly or the default context is farkeled somehow.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: When you clean up and subsequently restore the Core Data stack, how do you let your UI know about it?

Comment: I just ran another test; there IS data in the sqlite files, they are 
just NOT getting restored correctly (I checked the files in Finder, used 
SQLite Browser to view the contents, and verified the filename against the 
console log when running the app and they are the same!.).. no matter how many times I restart 
the app, the data is not showing up in the app... very strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after having a bit of a prod and a poke around, I believe `+[MagicalRecord cleanUp]` needs some love. Basically, the persistent store coordinator is being released without first removing the SQLite persistent store.

As you noted in another conversation we had about this, you need to reset the managed object context:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] reset];
```

Then iterate over all of your persistent stores to remove them:

```
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_defaultStoreCoordinator];
for (NSPersistentStore *store in [persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores]) {
    BOOL removed = [persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];

    if (!removed) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't remove persistent store: %@", error);
    }
}
```

After that, it should be safe to call `[MagicalRecord cleanUp]`, and then restore the entire stack as you have been (although you could opt to just attach the updated persistent store to the coordinator rather than completely blowing everything away).